# Ubuntu 22.04.4 unusable after getting kernel 6.5.0-25

Tags: upgrade, kernel

On my Lenovo T480s laptop running Ubuntu 22.04.4, upgrading to kernel 6.5.0-25 completely broke it. If it doesn't stall during boot, the desktop is sluggish and soon shows a dialog saying "gjs is not responding". Kubuntu is similar, either stalls at boot or gets into a barely responsive desktop (but no popup about gjs).

What's worse, now even a fresh installation is broken because it updates to kernel 6.5.0-25 during installation.

If I go into the GRUB menu during startup and choose the older kernel (either 6.5.0-18 or 6.5.0-21), then things are fine. But I was told kernel upgrades are important to keep up with security patches.

Another laptop (different model) works fine with 6.5.0-25, so it appears to be a hardware specific problem.

I'm evaluating replacing Windows with Ubuntu on my personal laptop, and this is discouraging. I'm semi proficient with shell commands, so any suggestion you have, any ideas to try, please throw them at me.

Comment: you may check `/var/log/dmesg`, `/var/log/syslog`, `/var/log/kern.log` and see if you can find something relevant. if GUI is having issues you may try ctrl-alt-f3 to drop into tty shell and continue troubleshooting from there

Answer (score 1):

Just as with any OS, some updates just won't work.

My advice is to simply remove the kernel (or any other package) that doesn't work properly, wait for next kernel update and see if that one is behaving better *(or find a new alternative for anything other)*.

`$ dpkg -l | grep -E "^ii.*linux-image"` will list installed kernels.
`$ sudo apt purge linux-image-5.13.0-52-generic` will remove that kernel, i.e. if that is listed in the second column of `dpkg -l` output.

**Important: Leave at least one kernel, one that you have verified to work.**
*Not entirely sure how hard (even possible?) it is to remove the one listed by `uname -a` - which is the one you're running at that moment* :-)

Earlier it was necessary to do a `sudo update-grub` afterwards,
but I believe it is done automatically nowadays, at the end of the apt run above.

A late note:
`$ sudo apt-mark hold pachagename`
will allow you to "hold" the kernel status, be it installed or NOT installed.