# ubuntu desktop 22.04 LTS kernel version: linux-6.5.0-27-generic causes my network UNCLAIMED

Tags: networking, drivers, kernel, 22.04

It seems that my Linux kernel auto-updated today, which caused my computer to lose internet access.
When I checked the hardware with the command `sudo lshw -c network`, I got the result of "network UNCLAIMED".
After trying all sorts of things, I was finally able to fix it by rolling back my kernel version to 6.5.0-25-generic(earlier than the current version).

So what exactly is causing this problem?

Comment: Probably, you have a hand-compiled driver for your WiFi. You will need to rebuild it for the current kernel.

Comment: Cause: incompatible driver / installation / components?  For practical handling of the failing kernel, see "Late note:" in: https://askubuntu.com/a/1507401/289138

Comment: We can only guess right now since you have not stated what hardware you have in your system, i.e.NIC.  If you have a RTL8168 the driver that is in the repos is not compatible with the 6.5 Kernels.  See:  https://askubuntu.com/q/1499659/231142